# Change Dropdown Select to List

Tags: html, css

I want to change my html select to list but do not know what to use for "value" and "onchange".

```
<select name="kf" onchange="$('#improve_search').submit();">
    <option value="0">Option 1</option> 
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Should be changed in div with listing

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="1">John Doe
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M5LZ5/)

The Tutorial for Dropdown is here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/
Demo for it is here: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index5.html

Comment: Oh yes the UNLIKE helped me a lot!

Comment: As you said you need to find a way to replace the `onchange`-event. This depends how you want the user to interact with the list. One option is to add a click event to the link and store in a variable which option was clicked. Do you still need help with this?